# Class decorator - modification of class field changes value in base class too

Tags: python, python-decorators

I wrote a class decorator with argument. This decorator needs to set value of class field `ID`. I am doing it in following way:

```
class Base:
    ID = "ID_Base"
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def func(self):
        pass

def Test(cnt):
    def createTest(className):
        class _Test(className):
            def __init__(self, n):
                className.__init__(self, n)

            def func(self):
                for n in range(cnt):
                    className.func(self)

        name = className.__name__ + "_Test"
        _Test.__name__ = name
        globals()[name] = _Test

        _Test.ID = className.ID + '_test'
        className.ID = ''
        return _Test

    return createTest

@Test(2)
class Derived(Base):
    pass

print(Base.ID)
print(Derived.ID)
print(Derived_Test.ID)
```

In function `createTest` first i have definition of class derived from given class type, then I modify class name for new `_Test` class and register it as global class in current module, then (in last block) I set `ID` attribute in `_Test` class and clear `ID` in class passed as parameter, and return new type. I did this to get following result:

```
ID_Base

ID_Base_test
```

However after running it I saw this:

```
ID_Base
ID_Base_test
ID_Base_test
```

Why it modifies attribute of `Derived` class instead of `_Test` created in decorator? And how to fix it?

I checked this using Python 2.6.6 (Linux) and Python 3.4.1 (ActivePython on Windows).

Edit: I also tried to set ID inside `_Test` class like below, but got the same result:

```
def Test(cnt):
    def createTest(className):
        class _Test(className):
            ID = className.ID + '_test'
```

Comment: where Derived_Test is coming from? does he have the annotation as well?

Comment: Derived_Test name is created in decorator, in particular in these lines: 
`name = className.__name__ + "_Test"`
`_Test.__name__ = name`
`globals()[name] = _Test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you got `ID_Base_test` from `print(Derived.ID)` is that there is an implicit assignment in the end of the decorating, which makes `Derived` references to `class Derived_Test`. Below code

```
@Test(2)
class Derived(Base):
    pass
```

kind of equals to

```
class Derived(Base):
    pass
Derived = Test(2)(Derived)
```

Try `print(Derived)` after the decorating, you will get `__main__.Derived_Test`.

update: see [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators) for some more explanation.

> A decorator is any callable Python object that is used to modify a function, method or class definition. A decorator is passed the original object being defined and returns a modified object, **which is then bound to the name in the definition**.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, this makes sense.